# How to remove dependency on .net 2.0 DTS libraries that dynamically builds DTS packages. How to use equivalent SSIS From C# .Net 4.6?

Tags: c#, ssis, ssis-2012, dts

We're doing a tech upgrade here at work.  Moving to SQL server 2012.  Also moving the Applications from .Net 2.0 to .Net 4.5+ so we can run the applications on newer OS(s) as well.  The problem is the application code created DTS packages on the fly and then ran task runners to read the uploaded files that the DTS packages were built from, into the database by running the packages.  The old code used a DTS library to create DTS packages.  Of course this code is no longer available.

I'm not trying to convert the DTS packages.  I'm trying to not, build them in the first place.  I could use SSIS instead but I'm not sure this is the way SSIS is used.  Can anyone tell me how to go about this using SSIS.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you understand what the DTS component does? I suspect it merely imports files. If this is the case, creating and running DTS files on the fly is complete overkill (creating SSIS packages on the fly would also be overkill). If this step is just importing data then you can easily achieve that directly in .Net. If you must create SSIS pacakges then you can use BIML to generate them automatically based on metadata, but in 15 years that will also be out of date!

Comment: LOL, Agreed Nick, the guy below is also suggesting BIML (I have never heard of it),  I'll take a look at this...  And also, your suspicion I'm sure is correct, it merely imports data into it's database through uploaded files.  This I can clearly see...  My current intention is to just write my own import routines to import the same files that are being uploaded without going the route of using any package.  I think this is all that is really necessary.  Though I will look at BIML to see if this may make some sense in this case...

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have little changes if you do not have source code for program generating SSIS packages.
The main problem here is that the program will be generating packages for the old SSIS version; it covers DTSX file format and component names. The component names are names of SSIS tasks and dataflow items and this is the way SSIS knows which task to execute next. Bad thing that most of these component names are changed in next versions of SSIS; moreover, some of the components have changed their parameter names.
If you leave your DTS generating program intact, you will always receive packages for obsolete version of SSIS. Simple packages could be transformed and upgraded by SSIS on the fly, but more complex packages should undergo manual upgrade.
In your case, there are several possibilities:

- Look for the source code and modify it to generate correct packages.
- Generate packages, save and then - upgrade with upgrade Wizard from SSIS or Visual Studio. Then you have to maintain packages manually in VS and run them by SQL Server Agent or batch files.
- Get familiar with [BIML](https://varigence.com/Biml) to dynamically generate packages based on metadata. This is way simpler that C# approach.

Personally I would opt for the third option.

Comment: Yes well indeed I don't want to turn an automated process into one that needs to manually convert the DTS packages into SSIS packages.  Indeed all that is really going on here is files are uploaded and need to be imported into a database.  I will look at BIML to see if it makes sense here but right now I'm thinking I can just write an import facility in C# that'll take care of it.  Thank you for your input!